# How to use Jackson Deserializer converter correctly

Tags: json, jackson

I wanted to try to use Jackson converter option to parse some custom strings. I have to deal with legacy string representations that have their own parser capable of taking a string and converting it into my desired class, `IceComTerm`. So I created a class that uses a field of `IceComTerm` type (with some extra fields removed for readability), and a converter

```
public final class PropertySetRepresentation {
    @JsonProperty("kbPrepare")
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = IceComTermJsonAdapter.IceComTermDeserializationConverter.class)
    private final IceComTerm kbPrepare;

    @JsonCreator
    public PropertySetRepresentation(@JsonProperty("kbPrepare")IceComTerm kbPrepare){
        this.kbPrepare = kbPrepare;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public IceComTerm getIceComRepresentation() {
        return kbPrepare;
    }
}


public class IceComTermJsonAdapter {    
    public static class IceComTermDeserializationConverter extends StdConverter<String, IceComTerm> {

        @Override
        public IceComTerm convert(String arg) {
            try {
                return IceComFactory.parseIceTerm(arg);
            } catch (IceComException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect IceComString, fails to parse as IceCom: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I expected it to be able to take a string and convert it into `IceComTerm` type that I needed. But when I run the following test, I get an exception:

```
@Test 
public void deserializePropertySetRepresentation() throws IOException {
    String propertySet = "{\"kbPrepare\":\"[forall,?circ,in,[:set,Circuit-36]]\"}";
    PropertySetRepresentation model = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(propertySet, PropertySetRepresentation.class);
    assertNotNull(model);
}

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of iceInterfaces.IceComTerm, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: {"kbPrepare":"[forall,?circ,in,[:set,Circuit-36]]"}; line: 1, column: 2]
```

I thought that if I use the converter, it does not matter that `IceComTerm` is an abstract class, because I am creating a specific instance by parsing the string in the converter. What I am missing here? I am using Jackson 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a possible bug here, possibly annotation from field is not "seen" by constructor. You could try to see if moving `@JsonDeserialize` next to constructor parameter makes a difference.

Either way, worth reporting a bug at: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/

Comment: Thanks. With a little more work I created a minimal test case which I think demonstrates that it is a bug. The issue seems to be that IceComTerm is abstract. If I use exactly the same approach with a non-abstract class, it's fine. Filed an issue at github as you suggested: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/795

Comment: Good thanks. There are couple of reasons why the problem may be triggered, but your usage looks correct, and the problem within Jackson handling of converter for constructor argument.